# как сделать под меню для данного меню (в CSS)

Tags: css, меню

```css
.bg{
    background-color: #234567;
    height: 70px;
}

.li1{
    display:inline-block; /*Для выравнивая в строчку а не в столбик*/
    padding:13px;
    color: white;
    font-size:25px;
    position: relative;/*Позиционирование меню по всему сайту*/
    top:5px; /*Опускаем вниз чтобы текст был посередине*/
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <ul>
     <a href="index.html"> <li class="li1">Турниры</li></a>
        <a href="Reıtıngı.html"><li class="li1">Рейтинги</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="li1">Бойцы</li></a>
        <a href="Новости.html"><li class="li1">Новости</li></a>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: А можно пример твоих попыток? И у тебя нарушена семантика, нужно в тег `<li></li>` оборачивать  тег `<a></a>`, а не наоборот, как у тебя

Comment: Я знаю как это правильно в HTML сделать скажите в css что нужно